# MVC pattern - Show only controller name in URL (hide index.php and action)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, model-view-controller

I'm using a Hosting Linux service provided by [Aruba](https://www.aruba.it/home.aspx) to run my website.

At this moment, my website URL design looks like this:

```
mysite.it/index.php?controller=&action=
```

and I want to hide `index.php` and the `action` parameter so my uri looks like:

```
mysite.it/controller
```

My basic folder structure is:

```
www.mysite.it/
  config/
  controller/
  lib/
  model/
  template/
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

Is there a solution to achieve this?

**Also**, I'd need to keep the original `document.URL`, because for example in some `.js` there are functions that search for the `action` parameter in the `URL`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: what you really want is a router...

Answer (score 0):

You could include the following text in your .htaccess file
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
Keep in mind that the rewrite engine must be active in your web server config.

Comment: I tried but basically it seems to change nothing... rewrite module is active

Comment: Have you checked if the configuration in the web server for the directory your web site is located allows Override?

Comment: Ok, your MVC calls the controllers not as part of the path but as an argument. So I think you culd try writing a RewriteRule for each controller this way: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action= [L]`

Comment: but is the query string kept this way? or do i just need to add [QSA]

Comment: it's not working, it redirects everything to the index :(

Comment: I'm typing "www.mysite.it/controller_name"

Comment: The RewriteRule will redirect everything you type to `index.php?controller=controller_name&action=`. So I think that you could check if there is a default action in the controller, or if you should include it explicitly. If the second case, you could type something like `www.mysite.it/controller_name/action` and the rewrite rule should include `...&action=$2  [L]`

Comment: so for example now I should change all previous links like `href=index.php?model=contacts&action=find-us`  to `href=contacts/find-us` ? And then the `mod_rewrite` should change the URL to just `www.mysite.it/contacts/find-us` ? Is this how it's supposed to work with your code (I'd need it to work this way)?

Comment: That's the idea. However it depends on the functionality and logic of your system. In order to stablish a more complex scheme you could use the routing module of your MVC. For example, I use Codeigniter, which has a really handy module to control routing. htaccess helps to simplify, but is not the ideal tool to manage routing.